# Converting float to an int (float2int) using only bitwise manipulation

Tags: c, assembly, floating-point, integer, arm

I am wondering if someone could set me in the right direction with a problem I am working on. I am trying to do what the following C function does using only ARM assembly and bit manipulation:

```
int float2int(float x) {
return (int) x;
}
```

I have already coded the reverse of this (int2float) without many issues. Im just unsure of where to start with this new problem.

For example:

```
3 (int) = 0x40400000 (float) 
0011 = 0 10000000 10000000000000000000000
```

Where 0 is the Sign Bit, 10000000 is the exponent, and 10000000000000000000000 is the mantissa/fraction.

Can someone simply point me in the right direction with this problem? Even a C pseudocode representation would be helpful. I know I need to extract the sign bit, extract the exponent and reverse the bias (127) and also extract the fraction but I just have no idea where to begin.

There is also the issue of if the float cannot be represented as an integer (because it overflows or is a NaN).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Here is the algorithm: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12343933/1707253

Comment: Do you have access to VFP or NEON? This can be done with VCVT in one instruction.

Comment: As a side note, it's fairly trivial to figure out how to implement this for your setup. Compile the above function with a C compiler; look at the assembler output.

Comment: @RobNapier: The compiler will likely generate a single instruction.

Comment: Yes it will (and does). Which if all he wants is "using only ARM assembly" (rather than requiring the actual algorithm) is perfect. (Though I believe it will only be one instruction if you have access to a VFP or NEON.)

Comment: Hmmm no access to VFP or NEON. I am already aware that I can compile the C function to -s (arm assembly), this usually produces some strange results however, and will probably use ARM's built in floating point libraries. I am trying to do this using only bit-by-bit manipulation. 

So far I am starting by separating the sign bit, Exponent, and mantissa from the input float into different registers.

Comment: Convert to `double`, add `2^53 + 2^52`, and grab the low 32 bits.  (This will give you some slightly funky rounding which you can almost-fix by adding 0.5 beforehand.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Assume int can hold all the precision of a float.
int float2int(float x) {
  int Sign = f_SignRawBit(x);
  unsigned Mantissa = f_RawMantissaBits(x);  // 0 - 0x7FFFFF
  int Expo = f_RawExpoBits(x); // 0 - 255
  // Form correct exponent and mantissa
  if (Expo == EXPO_MAX) {
    Handle_NAN_INF();
  }
  else if (Expo == EXPO_MIN) {
    Expo += BIAS + 1 - MantissaOffset /* 23 */;
  }
  else {
    Expo += BIAS - MantissaOffset /* 23 */;
    Mantissa |= ImpliedBit;
  }
  while (Expo > 0) {
    Expo--;
    // Add code to detect overflow
    Mantissa *= 2;
  }
  while (Expo < 0) {
    Expo++;
    // Add code to note last shifted out bit
    // Add code to note if any non-zero bit shifted out
    Mantissa /= 2;
  }

  // Add rounding code depending on `last shifted out bit` and `non-zero bit shifted out`.  May not be need if rounding toward 0.

  // Add code to detect over/under flow in the following
  if (Sign) {
    return -Mantissa;
  }
  return Mantissa;
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. Ill try to apply some of this algorithm to my ARM assembly interpretation.

Comment: @user3055632 Up-vote the posts you find useful.  Accept one that meets your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a number whose mantissa is your number (`00000011` in your example) and whose exponent is `01111111` (`127`, which is how 0 is stored in excess-of-127)
Count how many bits are from the LSb to the last set bit (not included). For each bit counted, add 1 to the exponent.

In your example: there are only one bit from the LSb to the last (most significant) bit set, so the exponent is added by 1 resulting in 128 (`10000000`).

Shift left your mantissa (your original number) so the left-most set bit is lost. Take into account that the shift must be performed using a variable capable of holding at least 23 bits. So in your example, the original mantissa is `00000000000000000000011` . You must shift left it until the left-most '1' is lost, resulting in `10000000000000000000000`
About the sign, if the original number is in 2-complement, simply take the MSb, and that will be your sign. In your example, 0 (positive)

So your result will be:
`Sign    : 0`
`Exponent: 10000000`
`Mantissa: 10000000000000000000000`

Another example: convert the short int number `-234` into a float.
`-234` using 2-complement is stored as `1111111100010110` (16 bits)

From here it's easy to get the sign: 1 (the MSb)

We must work with the absolute magnitude, so we complement the number to get the positive (magnitude) version. We can do it by xoring it with `1111111111111111`, then adding 1. This gives us `0000000011101010` (234)

Initial mantissa (using 23 bits): `00000000000000011101010`
Initial exponent: `01111111` (127)
Count how many bits are from the LSb to the left-most set bit, withouth including it. There are 7 bits. We add this to our exponent: `127+7=134 = 10000110`
The mantissa is shifted left until the left-most set bit is gone. This gives us:
`11010100000000000000000`

Our number will be: `1 10000110 11010100000000000000000`

Comment: Sorry if I confused you but it looks like you are describing how to convert an int to a float. I have already done this and now I am trying to convert the float value back to an int! Thanks for the response though

Answer (score 1):

Here is some basic C++ code to do the conversion.

```
#include <stdint.h>

union IntFloat
{
    uint32_t i;
    float    f;
};

int32_t Float32ToInt24( const float & x )
{
    IntFloat n;
    n.f = x;

    uint8_t  negative = ((n.i >> 31) & 0x1        )            ; // 0x10000000
    uint8_t  exponent = ((n.i >> 23) &  0xFF      )            ; // 0x7F800000
    uint32_t mantissa = ((n.i >>  0) &    0x7FFFFF) | 0x800000 ; // 0x007FFFFF implicit bit
    int32_t  i        = mantissa >> (22 - (exponent - 0x80));
    if( !exponent )
        return 0;
    if( negative )
        return -i;
    else
        return  i;
}
```

Note: Floats bigger then 2^24 will NOT convert properly to an integer due to the mantissa only have 24-bits of precision. i.e. adding the two floats 16777216.0 + 1.0 will have no effect!