# How floating point conversion was handled before the invention of FPU and SSE?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, sse, fpu

I am trying to understand how floating point conversion is handled at the low level. So based on my understanding, this is implemented in hardware. So, for example, SSE provides the instruction `cvttss2si` which converts a float to an int.

But my question is: was the floating point conversion always handled this way? What about before the invention of FPU and SSE, was the calculation done manually using Assembly code?

Comment: On an Intel 80286 i used the 8087-emulator(EM87.COM) from Ron Kimball. Now i found the docoment file on this page: http://docs1.chomikuj.pl/1816123580,PL,0,0,EM87.DOC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the processor, and there have been a *huge* number of different processors over the years.

FPU stands for "floating-point unit". It's a more or less generic term that can refer to a floating-point hardware unit for any computer system. Some systems might have floating-point operations built into the CPU. Others might have a separate chip. Yet others might not have hardware floating-point support at all. If you specify a floating-point conversion in your code, the compiler will generate whatever CPU instructions are needed to perform the necessary computation. On some systems, that might be a call to a subroutine that does whatever bit manipulations are needed.

SSE stands for "[Streaming SIMD Extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions)", and is specific to the x86 family of CPUs. For non-x86 CPUs, there's no "before" or "after" SSE; SSE simply doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion from floating-point to integer is considered a basic enough operation that the 387 instruction set already had such an instruction, `FIST`—although not useful for compiling the `(int)f` construct of C programs, as that instruction used the current rounding mode.

Some RISC instruction sets have always considered that a dedicated conversion instruction from floating-point to integer was an unnecessary luxury, and that this could be done with several instructions accessing the IEEE 754 floating-point representation. One basic scheme  might look like [this blog post](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/03/nearbyintf2), although the blog post is about rounding a float to a 
float representing the nearest integer.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to the standardization of IEEE 754 arithmetic, there were many competing vendor-specific ways of doing floating-point arithmetic.  These had different ranges, precision, and different behavior with respect to overflow, underflow, signed zeroes, and undefined results such as 0/0 or sqrt(-1).

However, you can divide floating point implementations into two basic groups: hardware and software.  In hardware, you would typically see an opcode which performs the conversion, although coprocessor FPUs can complicate things.  In software, the conversion would be done by a function.

Today, there are still soft FPUs around, mostly on embedded systems.  Not too long ago, this was common for mobile devices, but soft FPUs are still the norm on smaller systems.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation of the compiler.  You can implement floating point math in just about any language (an example in C: http://www.jhauser.us/arithmetic/SoftFloat.html), and so usually the compiler's runtime library will include a software implementation of things like floating point math (or possibly the target hardware has always supported native instructions for this - again, depends on the hardware) and instructions which target the FPU or use SSE are offered as an optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the floating point operations are a challenge for hardware engineers, as they require much hardware (leading to higher costs of the final product) and consume much power. There are some architectures that do not contain a floating point unit. There are also architectures that do not provide instructions even for basic operations like integer division. The ARM architecture is an example of this, where you have to implement division in software. Also, the floating point unit comes as an optional coprocessor in this architecture. It is worth thinking about this, considering the fact that ARM is the main architecture used in embedded systems.

IEEE 754 (the floating point standard used today in most of the applications) is not the only way of representing real numbers. You can also represent them using a fixed point format. For example, if you have a 32 bit machine, you can assume you have a decimal point between bit 15 and 16 and perform operations keeping this in mind. This is a simple way of representing floating numbers and it can be handled in software easily.

Answer (score 1):

Before Floating Point Units doesn't really apply, since some of the earliest computers made back in the 1940's supported floating point numbers: [wiki - first electro mechanical computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer#The_first_electromechanical_computers).

On processors without floating point hardware, the floating point operations are implemented in software, or on some computers, in microcode as opposed to being fully hardware implemented: [wiki - microcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode) , or the operations could be handled by separate hardware components such as the Intel x87 series: [wiki - x87](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X87) .

Answer (score 1):

> But my question is: was the floating point conversion always handled this way?

No, there's no x87 or SSE on architectures other than x86 so no `cvttss2si` either

Everything you can do with software, you can also do in hardware and vice versa.

The same to float conversion. If you don't have the hardware support, just do some bit hacking. There's nothing low level here so you can do it in C or any other languages easily. There is already a lot of solutions on SO

- [Converting Int to Float/Float to Int using Bitwise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20302904/995714)
- [Casting float to int (bitwise) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12342926/995714)
- [Converting float to an int (float2int) using only bitwise manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20318911/995714)
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The exponent was changed to 0 by shifting the mantissa, denormalizing the number. If the result was too large for an int an exception was generated. Otherwise the denormalized number (minus the factional part and optionally rounded) is the integer equivalent.