# MIPS convert float into an integer

Tags: assembly, floating-point, integer, mips

I've tried looking at it a couple different ways, one of them was using binary to shift left/right but I just wasn't able to find a combination to make it work for anything besides a few selected numbers each time. So how do you convert a float into an integer?

```
.data
five: .float 10.0

.text

main:
    la  $a1 five 
    l.s $f12 ($a1) 
    #conversion here

    li $v0 2# print float, which will print 10.0 (should print integer)
    syscall

    li $v0 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Do you have a MIPS instruction-set reference? You might want to have a look at `cvt*.*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm not an expert on *MIPS* arch.

As suggested in the comments, a quick lookup for *MIPS FP reference* gives the desired instruction: [cvt.w.s](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node20.html).

```
.data
    five: .float 5.0
.text

#Convert five into an integer
la $t1, five
l.s $f12, ($t1)             #f12 = five
cvt.w.s $f0, $f12           #f0 = (int) five


#Print five
li $v0, 2
syscall

#Print (int)five
li $v0, 1
mfc1 $a0, $f0               #a0 = (int)five
syscall

#Exit
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

This will print

> 5.05

As there is no space between the *5.0* and the *5*.

If you want to do it by hand, you can start from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318911/converting-float-to-an-int-float2int-using-only-bitwise-manipulation).

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed to see. I'll have to take a closer look at cvt.

Comment: The contents of a floating-point register can be moved to a GPR with `mfc1` (e.g. `mfc1 $a0, $f0`), which removes the need for the extra load and store to memory.

Comment: @Michael Super duper thanks! Those loads/stores were ugly.